# Getting SOAP request as POJO in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

In our project we expose a number of web-services that were generated from a wsdl. After generating them, I can see that the requests and responses are mapped to POJOs and when I am making the response, I just set a new POJO. This works really nice. However, I have a problem with the request. When we receive the request I expected that the payload will be a POJO mapping the parameters from the request. The payload becomes actually an array of objects. I can access the values but this is not very comfortable. You can take a look at the picture.
[image]

I can see that the under "Variables" in the method it is correctly matched to the POJO we would like to have. Is there some setting that I am missing somewhere so that we can get the payload to be mapped to correct POJO type?

Comment: What SOAP style do you use: doc/lit? Does the generated service interface accept a request POJO or multiple arguments?

Comment: @DavidDossot In the generated ILegacy class from the wsdl I can see why the request is like this:

Comment: public se.comaround.ws.ArrayOfMenuContentItem getMenuContent(
        @WebParam(name = "loginName", targetNamespace = "http://blablk.com")
        java.lang.String loginName,
        @WebParam(name = "passWord", targetNamespace = "http://blablk.com")
        java.lang.String passWord,
        @WebParam(name = "parentID", targetNamespace = "http://blablk.com")
        java.lang.Integer parentID
    );

Comment: Clearly that is the issue: `getMenuContent` takes 4 parameters instead of on single wrapper object. Asking again: what SOAP style is the WSDL?

Comment: @DavidDossot We dont have a SOAPBinding annotation, so I guess it is doc/lit
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/Developing+a+Service#DevelopingaService-OptionalAnnotations
We imported the wsdl as a file to generate the service and this is the default behaviour I guess

Comment: Thank you. Try re-running the WSDL to Java codegen but this time with wrapper style **disabled**, see: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html#WSDLtoJava-wrapperstyle

Comment: @DavidDossot Thanks a lot, David! I regenerated the source files with the wrapper style disabled as explained by the article. I think it is good to just put this as a response to my original post so that I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-run the WSDL to Java codegen but this time with wrapper style **disabled**, see: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html#WSDLtoJava-wrapperstyle